# Get some unique hardware info from user's system

Tags: vb6, hardware

i want my application  be available only for one system, and i want to get one of  hardware informations that be *consistent, unique and available* in all systems... .

In your opinion, what info is the best? and how i can get it with Visual Basic 6?

Thank you

Comment: Not so easy. The amount of hardware info you get depends on the rights with which the user is running your software. If you can be sure to have full rights, you could take into account hard drive id, etc, which you can obtain in VB using WMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC addresses and hard drive serial numbers are the most available unique hardware ID I know of. CPUs were going to introduce a [serial number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) feature years ago, but the idea was squashed due to privacy concerns.

[VB6 Code MAC Example](http://www.andreavb.com/forum/viewtopic_2917.html)

[VB6 Hard Drive Serial Number Exmaple](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbpowerpacks/thread/0e9a097d-c22c-4b70-ad50-106d680fa5b3)

Comment: Note that both of those can change at any time. MAC addresses can be changed and swapping a NIC will cause a new one to be used.